# tvOS Focus button in a Subview

Tags: swift, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller, focus-engine

I am using AVPlayerController and I have added a subview on top of AVPlayerController. As Soon the subview is displayed I want to shift focus from the player to the Subview and focus the UIButton added on top of that Subivew. I have tried preferredfocusview but its a read-only property and I cannot change it. Can anyone pelase assist. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `preferredFocusView` is deprecated so you should use `preferredFocusEnvironments` instead.

It is a computed property, which means you don't assign to it, you override it:

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
//if subview exists, return the subview or the button, whichever is focusable
    return [subview]
//otherwise use the default implementation of AVPlayerController
    return super.preferredFocusEnvironments
}
```

You should also call `self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()` and `self.updateFocusIfNeeded()` to request a focus update when you add the subview.

Comment: I have some buttons inside a view, the view get focused but buttons don't get focus. How to solve this ?